# Accessing js/css/img resources on IIS server behind NAT router

Tags: c#, webforms, nat

I have a web application deployed on IIS server; all the resources are accessed from the server; resource path set accordingly. I am able to access the application using the without any issues; since the application has to be accessed outside our network the security team introduced the NAT router. While trying to access the application using public IP provided by the NAT router my resources(js/css/img) are failing to load.
How do I set the resource path if NAT router is in between?
This is how the path looks now `bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css`

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure your resource path is available as a virtual or physical folder under your site
2. Your network setup may be blocking images, try using ngrok (https://ngrok.com/) to expose your local host and ensure it actually works correctly when accessed via public web. If it does this means your router is the issue.